# @login_required doesn't seem too recognize that I'm authenticated - django app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm a newbie python developer and I'm trying to develop a simple language school management app. I've created login page, which works and compares credentials to user's credentials provided in database. But even after succsessful authentication ('Success' is printed out in terminal) it seems that @login_required decorator doesn't see me as authenticated. What could be the  reason? I'll provide all the data you need. Here's my simple views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print('Success')
            return redirect("dashboard")
        else:
            error_message = "Invalid login credentials"
            return render(request, "login.html", {"error_message": error_message})
    return render(request, "login.html")


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("login")


@login_required()
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, "dashboard.html")
```

I used custom models and my custom authentication func looks like that:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import Teacher


class TeacherBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            teacher = Teacher.objects.get(username=username)
        except Teacher.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if teacher.check_password(password):
            return teacher

        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was missing these options in settings.py file:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard/"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "student_management.Teacher"
```